# Is an APFS formatted drive underpinned by HFS+?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, apfs, hfs+

When I formatted my drive with APFS this is the output that Disk Utility delivered. It says right at the beginning `Formatting disk7s2 as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with name External HD`. So is an APFS formatted drive underpinned by HFS+?

```
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk7s2 as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with name External HD
Initialised /dev/rdisk7s2 as a 11 TB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume with a 524288k journal

Mounting disk
Creating a new empty APFS Container
Unmounting Volumes
Switching disk7s2 to APFS
Creating APFS Container
Created new APFS Container disk9
Preparing to add APFS Volume to APFS Container disk9
Creating APFS Volume
Created new APFS Volume disk9s1
Mounting APFS Volume
Setting volume permissions

Operation successful.
```

Comment: You didn't format the drive, you reformatted an existing partition. `disk7s2` is the  2nd partition on disk 7.

Comment: Alex: Which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ventura 13.2.1.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not quite sure now how I formatted it. I noticed that the there were a couple of copy errors (via `rsync`). Could the way I have formatted the drive and partition lead to inefficiencies?

Comment: No. The format method itself could not do that.

Comment: Are there any advantages/disadvantages to having the drive formatted in HFS+ and a partition (the only partition) in APFS?

Comment: That would be a separate question; one which has most likely been asked & answered before.